# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I'm totally cool with this [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) error. How can I tolerate it? Is there a flag or checkbox for it?

You get it when you do stuff like:

```
v && arr.push(v);
```

as opposed to:

```
if (v) {
    arr.push(v);
}
```

Both do the same exact thing. If you put:

```
window.test = function(v) {
    'use strict';
    var arr = [];
    if (v) {
        arr.push(v);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

into the [minifier](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) it minifies down to this anyway:

```
window.test=function(a){var b=[];a&&b.push(a);return b};
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I don't think JSLint has an option to turn that off.

[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) (a fork with more options) has an option for it, though: The `expr` option, documented as "if ExpressionStatement should be allowed as Programs".

Comment: @diEcho: You can also download and use it locally (that's what I do). I run it via NodeJS with my preferred options set, *dramatically* helps my confidence in correct code. :-)

Comment: Can describe more please, why that warning happened?

Answer (score 37):

You can add the following line to ignore that warning:

> /*jshint -W030 */

You can read more about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140521021850/http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call).

Comment: The answer is completely unrelated to the question, which was about JSLint, not JSHint.

Comment: Yet its still the most useful answer for the majority of people who land here.

Comment: "completely unrelated"?  Because JSHint is completely unrelated to JSLint?

Answer (score 11):

People who are looking how to suppress it when using [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). You can ingnore it by writing the following comment just above the line [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions#top)

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
```

You can also suppress the warning for the entire file by placing the following comment at the very top of the file

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
```

Comment: I recommend you to also provide the link of the documentation of this specific rule [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions#top)

Answer (score 9):

There's no option for this in JSLint. You can circumvent it using:

```
var dummy = v && arr.push(v);
```

NB: `dummy` evaluates to `true` after that.

Another workaround could be:

```
function expression(statement) { 
 'use strict';
 return statement; 
}
expression(v && arr.push);
```

Comment: It'll work but it's silly. The minifier will actually sort that out and but for readability it'd be better to just use the `if` statement than that IMO.

Comment: That's true. But you asked for a way to tolerate is. Added another workaround. It's like Crockford said somewhere: *jsLint is designed to be a pain in the ass for programmers* ;~)

Comment: WRONG the wonderful && hack does not work in jsLint... maybe depends on version...