# Recently i am getting this errors but in the past I didn't get

Tags: reactjs

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

index.js:1 src\index.js
Line 109:1:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Please Help out

Comment: Using Eslint or Jslint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573277/react-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534031/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression